# How to float list items to left in a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

Below is a css clickable drop down menu. Here I want to float the list elements to left, not the whole dropdown menu just the list items that I get on clicking drop down.

```css
.onclick-menu {
  float:right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.onclick-menu-content {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
   position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0.5s;
}
.onclick-menu:focus {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.onclick-menu-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu">dropdown
    <ul class="onclick-menu-content">
        <li>down1</li>
        <li>This one is just a long</li>
        <li>down3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can just use margin: -20px to move everything to the left in the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add some CSS to clear the default list styling:

```
.onclick-menu-content {
  ...
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
```

[fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/5xL12dv0/2/)

To have everything aligned to the right side of the page, add an extra

```
right:0;
```

to the CSS. Check this [second fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xL12dv0/3/)

Comment: thanks Mr.white but when there is lengthy list item ,it still goes to right beyond the visible page,check my snippet, is there a way to make list items appear left of `ul`,like fb notifications.

Comment: By 'left of the UL' you mean everything aligned right so that the menu is sticking out on the left?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5xL12dv0/3/ ? In there I've added a 'right:0' to the positioning of the UL

Answer (score 1):

`.onclick-menu-content li{display:inline-block; float:left;}`

Comment: You need to set some width to the `UL` element.